# How can I use getcontext() in recycler adapter class?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, this

I have adapter class that extends recyclerview.adapter and I need to use following code in this class but it has error on "this".

```
public void addItems(int howMany){
    if (howMany > 0) {
        int lastInsertedIndex = 11;
        for (int i = lastInsertedIndex + 1; i <= lastInsertedIndex + howMany; i++) {
            mList.add(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("Item " + i));
            notifyItemInserted(mList.size() - 1);
        }
        lastInsertedIndex = lastInsertedIndex + howMany;
    }
}
```

how to fix this error ?

Comment: you must pass activity context when you call adapter before it to set in recyclerview.

Comment: @KrishnaJ how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the context in the constructor of the adapter like:

```
Context context;
public YourAdapter( Context c) {
    this.context = c;
}
```

Now use this context in place of this.

To pass the context :

```
mAdapter = new YourAdapter(getContext());
recyclerview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

If you are using your adapter from an Activity then use ActivityName.this in place of getContext().

Answer (score 2):

In your recycler adapter class

```
 private Context context;
//some code...//

@Override
    public CartListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        context=parent.getContext(); //here get the context
        View cartItemRow= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cartitem_row_detail,parent,false);
        return new CartListViewHolder(cartItemRow);
    }
```

use it throughout the adapter class... no need to pass context or anything..

Answer (score 0):

In activity You have to do like this:

**Activity**

```
    mAdapter = new CardViewDataAdapter(bank_list, context);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

I adapter You can get like this:

**Adapter**

```
public CardViewDataAdapter(ArrayList<Bank> bank_list, Context context) {
    dataSet = bank_list;
    ctx = context;
 }
```

Comment: context = getApplicationContext();